# About Django and static files in deployment from pythonanywhere

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

what can I do if I want to collectstatic again in pythonanywhere? I did it because I remove oneline in my remote repository and when I collectstatic it didn't work (new styles don't apply) so what can I do?

I'm not an speaker of English.

Comment: Did the `collectstatic` management command print out any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

You should check whitenoise. It helps in maintaining static files in deployment  in django.

Comment: It was cache's fault and also my fault ofc, thanks to answered me